# angular SocketIoConfig websocket connection on heroku

Tags: angular, heroku, socket.io

I currently have a simple WebSocket connection in my angular app using socket.io. When I run my code via ng serve it works fine, however after I deploy to my Heroku app I get a 'net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED' error. It appears that somewhere after setting my SocketIoConfig the hostname changes to null, but this only happens on Heroku.

The console log in my app.module.ts shows on:

1. **ng serve** is correctly formed as 'http://localhost:4444'
2. **Heroku** is correctly formed as 'https://app-name.herokuapp.com'

However, when running on Heroku my console error is:

> GET https://null/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N1tbO9M
>   net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Why does the hostname change to null? What am I missing?

app.enter code heremodule.ts file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';

import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { PlayerStatsComponent } from './player-stats/player-stats.component';
import { playerName, filterByRole, orderHeroBy, greaterThan10m, replace } from './custom.pipe';
import { HomePageComponent } from './home-page/home-page.component';
import { WinrateComponent } from './winrate/winrate.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ngx-socket-io';

let port = ( window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ) ? ':8080' : '';
let url = `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}${port}`;
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: url, options: {} };
console.log( config );

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        PlayerStatsComponent,
        playerName,
        filterByRole,
        greaterThan10m,
        orderHeroBy,
        HomePageComponent,
        WinrateComponent,
        replace
    ],
    imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        ChartsModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        FormsModule,
        SocketIoModule.forRoot(config)
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

server.js file

```
//Install express server
const express = require( 'express' );
const path = require( 'path' );

const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');

// webserver
const app = express();
app.use( express.static( __dirname + '/dist/statwatchII' ) );
app.get( '/*', function( req, res ) {
    res.sendFile( path.join( __dirname+'/dist/statwatchII/index.html' ) );
});

// socketserver
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const server = http.Server(app);
const io = require( 'socket.io' )( server );

io.on( "connection", ws => {
    console.log( 'connected' );
} )

server.listen( port, () => { console.log( `listening on port: ${port}`) } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the WebSocket Client to connect in a Heroku deploy I needed to do two things.

Remove the hardcoding of the web socket server port number ( as suggested above by Tin Nguyen ). This now means that the port is only hardcoded for the localhost.

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const server = http.Server(app);
const io = require( 'socket.io' )( server );
server.listen( port, () => { console.log( `listening on port: ${port}`) } );
```

I also updated the clientside socket.io config to set the URL to undefined if the hostname is not localhost. In socket.io if the URL is undefined it sets it manually from the source hostname.

```
let hostname = window.location.hostname;
let url = ( hostname === 'localhost' ) ? `${window.location.protocol}//${hostname}:8080` : undefined;
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: url, options: {} };
```

Answer (score 1):

Your app is not deploying correctly.

> 1. ng serve is correctly formed as 'http://localhost:4444'
> 2. Heroku is correctly formed as 'https://app-name.herokuapp.com:4444'

This is not true. When deploying a web application on Heroku you no longer explicitly add the port number after the hostname. Heroku's DNS automatically translates the hostname to an ip address + port number.
Furthermore you do not get to decide what the port number is going to be.

```
app.listen( process.env.PORT || 8080 );
```

With this line you are making your webpage available at `http://localhost:8080/` on localhost (assuming you haven't set the environment variable `$PORT`). On Heroku your webpage will be available at `https://app-name.herokuapp.com/`

```
server.listen(4444);
```

This line will work on localhost. But it will not work on Heroku since you cannot explicitly decide on what port your web application is running.

You actually don't need two ports since you can combine http and ws. You can do something like this.

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', () => { /* … */ });
server.listen( process.env.PORT || 8080 );
```

I've deployed d-zone on Heroku with a similar tactic. Here you can find the relevant source code:
https://github.com/vegeta897/d-zone/blob/63730fd7f44d2716a31fcae55990d83c84d5ffea/script/websock.js
Here is the deploy link: https://heroku.com/deploy?template=https://github.com/vegeta897/d-zone/tree/heroku

Comment: I have rejigged my code taking what you say into consideration. It seems to have not changed the behaviour I am experiencing. I now try to connect the web socket client to the web socket server on either:

localhost:8080 ( for dev )
or
https://my-app.herokuapp.com.

I believe the problem is with my client-side code rather than serverside. as I continue to get the following error clientside:

GET https://null/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N1uMp2l net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: I have updated my question with the latest code change I tried with your suggestions.